# Spring Boot: Adding @Transactional produces java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.util.PartialOrder$PartialComparable

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle, spring-boot, kotlin

Spring Boot 1.4.2 with Kotlin and Gradle 3.0. When we try to add @Transactional to the controller method, the resulting jar is failing to start with error:

```
2016-12-14 15:22:57.055 ERROR 4666 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'registrator': Error creating bean with name 'personRegistrator' defined in file [/home/voksiv/projects/svc-bereg/build/classes/main/com/beget/bereg/services/internal/person/commands/PersonRegistrator.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRegistrator' defined in file [/home/voksiv/projects/svc-bereg/build/classes/main/com/beget/bereg/services/internal/person/commands/PersonRegistrator.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at com.beget.bereg.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:15) [main/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRegistrator' defined in file [/home/voksiv/projects/svc-bereg/build/classes/main/com/beget/bereg/services/internal/person/commands/PersonRegistrator.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.sortAdvisors(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:73) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:91) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.util.PartialOrder$PartialComparable
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
```

build gradle is:

```
group 'templateProject'

buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.0.5-2'
        springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

dependencies {
    // Kotlin
    compile  group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-stdlib', version: "$kotlinVersion"

    // Spring
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: "$springBootVersion"
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '1.10.5.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.5'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP
    compile group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: '2.5.1'

    // JPA & Hibernate
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.0.Final'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate', version: '3.5.4-Final'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.5.Final'

    // Db Flyway migrations
    compile group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: '4.0.3'
    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.3.170'


    testCompile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-stdlib', version: "$kotlinVersion"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = "com.example.ApplicationKt"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    }
}
```

Honestly - We have no idea what to do next. gradle dependencies show that aspectjweaver exists and it has a correct version.

After spending two days with it and making no progress, we are open to any ideas.

[Repo](https://github.com/voksiv/kotlin-spring-boot-template) if anyone interested in code.

Comment: why did you mark TransactionTest as a @Component?

Comment: Having the same probem, I would be interested to know why adding @Transactional causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

Since i think the repository code isn't the same as the code that produced the exception i will guess, that you maybe haven't declared the class as 'open'? That is necessary because the @Transactional functionality works by using Spring AOP which needs classes that aren't internally declared as static - i.e. open in kotlin... when i remember correctly that is going to be fixed with spring framework 5.0.

Alternatively have you tried constructor injection without the @Autowired annotation (should be working since Spring Boot 1.4) like this:

```
@Controller
open class ExampleController(var repository: ExampleEntityRepository) {

}
```

btw: to annotate a controller with both of

```
@RestController
@ResponseBody
```

is not necessary since @RestController will add @ResponseBody internally on its own